# Background Service Android Using RxAndroidBle

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-background, android-ble, rxandroidble

When I connect, write, and notify using backgorund service, connection running well but when I closed the application connection between service and BLE device lost. Can I still connect to device using background service in Android?

Comment: You should use a foreground service to maintain the connection even if the activity is shut down.

Comment: Oke that resolve for me, thank you very much. Can I remove connection when foreground service was closed?